# Where should I place a dynamic library (dynlib) to be linked to a Cocoa application?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, autotools, dynamic-linking

Suppose I am going to use some library that is installable through autotools in my Cocoa application. Where should I "place" it? Should I run `./configure && make` and then copy the `.dynlib` it to my Xcode project? Or is it better to execute `./configure && make && sudo make install` and then configure my project to link to it? In the latter case, would the Xcode builder be smart enough to copy the library to the bundle?

Comment: To link against a library using Xcode, simply drag the library into your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not working with Mac OS X anymore. Anyway, I believe the preferred solution is either to link to the library statically or include the `.dynlib` in the bundle.

(I tried to install the library using autotools (aka `./configure && make && sudo make install`) and then add the parameters to the project configuration; the result was that my application did not work in any machine where the library was not installed.)